# Extending PMA Rudin theorem 6.10 to countable set of discontinuties.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

In Baby Rudin book, a theorem states that

> Suppose f is bounded on [a,b], f has only finitely many points of discontinuity on [a,b], and α is continuous at every point at which f is discontinuous. Then f∈R(α).

Here is the proof given by Rudin:

> Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Put $M = \sup \left\vert f(x) \right\vert$, let $E$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous. Since $E$ is finite and $\alpha$ is continuous at every point of $E$, we can cover $E$ by finitely many disjoint intervals $\left[ u_j, v_j \right] \subset [a, b]$ such that the sum of the corresponding differences $\alpha\left(v_j\right) - \alpha \left( u_j \right)$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Furthermore, we can place these intervals in such a way that every point of $E \cap (a, b)$ lies in the interior of some $\left[ u_j, v_j \right]$.

> Remove the segments $\left( u_j, v_j \right)$ from $[a, b]$. The remaining set $K$ is compact. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$, and there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\left\vert f(s) - f(t) \right\vert < \varepsilon$ if $s \in K$, $t \in K$, $\left\vert s-t \right\vert < \delta$.

> Now form a partition $P = \left\{ x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n \right\}$ of $[a, b]$, as follows: Each $u_j$ occurs in $P$. Each $v_j$ occurs in $P$. No point of any segment $\left( u_j, v_j \right)$ occurs in $P$. If $x_{i-1}$ is not one of the $u_j$, then $\Delta \alpha_i < \delta$.

> Note that $M_i - m_i \leq 2M$ for every $i$, and that $M_i - m_i \leq \varepsilon$ unless $x_{i-1}$ is one of the $u_j$. Hence,
> $$ U(P, f, \alpha) - L(P, f, \alpha) \leq \left[ \alpha(b) - \alpha(a) \right] \varepsilon + 2M \varepsilon.$$

**Now my question is can we assume instead of finite set of discontinuities can we assume it to be countable set**.

My approach is since α is continuous we can choose $u_j$,$v_j$ such that $\alpha\left(v_j\right) - \alpha \left( u_j \right)$<$\varepsilon$/$2^j$. Hence sum of the corresponding differences $\alpha\left(v_j\right) - \alpha \left( u_j \right)$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

Is this correct approach or I am missing something?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: How would the proof work if, for example, $f$ is discontinuous at every rational number in $[a,b]$? E.g. the [Thomae function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Comment: Thomae function is in fact Riemann integrable. Since is discontinuous at every rational number and hence countable number of discontinuities and I can write it as $x_1$,$x_2$,...... and after that choosing interval [$u_j$,$v_j$] the way I proposed.

Comment: Yes, it's Riemann integrable, but the above proof would not work because there's no way to cover $E$ (the set of points where $f$ is discontinuous) with **disjoint** intervals unless you use trivial intervals where $u_j = v_j$.

Comment: Understood your point. We need disjoint intervals. Thanks for the clarification